# how to stop Spring AMQP annotated message listener from receiving messages

Tags: spring-amqp

when my Spring AMQP message listener recognizes an error, I want to stop receiving messages from the queue. When I have a ListenerContainer configured as bean, I can call stop() on it.

Can I do something similar, when I have configured my listener with an endpoint annotation? E.g. is it possible to inject the ListenerContainer the container has created for me?

thx,
  tchick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, find `@RabbitListener#id()` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The unique identifier of the container managing for this endpoint.
 * <p>If none is specified an auto-generated one is provided.
 * @return the {@code id} for the container managing for this endpoint.
 * @see org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)
 */
String id() default "";
```

So, you have to inject to your target service the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` and use it to get access to desired `ListenerContainer` by its `id`.

Comment: What about for publishing (producing) @Artem Bilan

Comment: Sorry, your cimment is not clear. Please, consider to raise a new SO thread with more context to let to know exactly what you want from us. Thanks for understanding